# Ruby - Convert Integer to ASCII value

Tags: ruby, ascii

I have been looking around the internet, but have not found a way to convert a integer into a ascii value in Ruby.

Anyone have any idea how?

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
your_number.chr
```

here's the [doc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-chr)

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you can use `chr` to convert integer to ascii.

```
>> 65.chr
A
```